# Issue Upgrading Pulsar from Version 2.x to 3.x - PodDisruptionBudget Kind Not Found in Kubernetes

Tags: apache-pulsar

I am encountering a challenging problem while attempting to upgrade Pulsar from version 2.x to 3.x. To perform the upgrade, I executed a Helm command with the following values YAML: [link to Helm values YAML.](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/3631259)

Here is the Helm command I used for the upgrade:

`helm upgrade --namespace pulsar --version 3.0.0 -f customized-values-pulsar-3x.yaml pulsar apache/pulsar --wait --timeout 10m`

However, the upgrade failed with the following Error message:

```
helm upgrade --namespace pulsar --version 3.0.0 -f customized-values-pulsar-3x.yaml pulsar apache/pulsar --wait --timeout 10m
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: unable to build kubernetes objects from current release manifest: [resource mapping not found for name: "pulsar-bookie" namespace: "pulsar" from "": no matches for kind "PodDisruptionBudget" in version "policy/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "pulsar-broker" namespace: "pulsar" from "": no matches for kind "PodDisruptionBudget" in version "policy/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "pulsar-zookeeper" namespace: "pulsar" from "": no matches for kind "PodDisruptionBudget" in version "policy/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first]
```

It seems like there is an issue with the PodDisruptionBudget kind in the Kubernetes cluster. I have verified that the Kubernetes APIs are correctly configured.

Additional Information:

Kubernetes Cluster Version: 1.25 (Running on Amazon EKS)
Helm Version: 3.11.3
kubectl Client Version: 1.28.4
It seems like there is an issue with the PodDisruptionBudget kind in the Kubernetes cluster. I have verified that the Kubernetes APIs are correctly configured. The Helm values YAML used for the upgrade can be found [here.](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/3631259)

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or assistance in resolving this matter. Thank you!

Comment: I have updated the solution, and it is now part of the official Pulsar README.

https://github.com/apache/pulsar-helm-chart#recovering-from-helm-upgrade-error-unable-to-build-kubernetes-objects-from-current-release-manifest